# Listing all certificates on a computer

Tags: c#, certificate

I am trying to list all certificates that are located on a computer. I have read all of the examples I have come across on the net, but nothing is working. I have tried it on both a Windows 7 and a Windows 8 computer without any errors. Here is what I have so far:

```
public void Analyser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var certificates = store.Certificates;

    foreach (var certificate in certificates)
    {
        var friendlyName = certificate.FriendlyName;
        var xname = certificate.GetName(); //obsolete
        Console.WriteLine(friendlyName);
    }

    store.Close();       
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, if you have a specific question that you would like answered you should post that instead.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("My");
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
foreach (X509Certificate2 mCert in store.Certificates){
//TODO's
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ILSpy, the `X509Store` class constructor defaults to `StoreName.My` if you don't specify it. Is your personal certificate store empty?

To avoid ambiguity I recommend that you always specify both the store name and location, e.g.

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
```